# addEventListenter not working with element.submit()

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

Why is event submit not working, when `$('form').submit()` is?

But it working when press enter in input field

```js
document.getElementById("mform1").addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  alert('123')
});
```

```html
<form id="mform1" name="mform1" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <input type="text">
</form>
```

Comment: `$('form').submit()` is a jQuery statement and I can't see no jQuery in your given example..

Comment: Please describe more clearly what the expected and actual result is?

Comment: Don't mix jQuery and DOM methods.

Comment: by default, $ is alias of document.querySelector

Comment: @TiếnMạnh: In some console environments it is, but it's not a alias in general.

Answer (score 4):

The submit event only fires when the user submits the form. It never fires when JavaScript submits it.

You can fake it by explicitly triggering an event:

```js
document.getElementById("mform1").addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  alert('123')
});

var fake_submit = new Event("submit");
document.getElementById("mform1").dispatchEvent(fake_submit);
```

```html
<form id="mform1" name="mform1" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <input type="text">
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use only jQuery:

```js
$( "#mform1" ).submit( function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert( "123" );
} );
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<form id="mform1" name="mform1" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <input type="text">
</form>
```

Comment: Maybe you'll have cross-browser troubles. For example, `addEventListener` is not in IE11-.

Comment: @MiquelAl.Vicens: Yes it is. IE added it in IE9. Browser compatibility isn't relevant to the question anyway.

Comment: Right, it was IE9.